# Custom Authorizer returns 403 but not calling lambda

Tags: aws-api-gateway

The screenshot below shows 2 subsequent calls to my API. The first call works as expected, while the second returns 403, even though is uses the same exact JWT in the Authorization header.

[image]

The execution log for the first call looks like this (I highlighted the token):

[image]

The execution log for the second call looks like this (token highlighted again):

[image]

And finally, the log from my Authorizer method looks like this (you'll notice it is only called once):

[image]

Any pointers? Is it a caching issue with the policy? Something else that pops out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. As described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html), the policy returned from the authorizer is cached. That doesn't play well with the fact I was giving access to the specific resource requested - it means the cached policy was only allowing access to the first method I called.

Comment: so the solution was to turn down the cache time to 0?

Comment: Fixing the policy document to have the correct resource @damitj07 could be a better solution.